# jQuery-ui and roundabout conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a web page where am using `jquery-ui` for accordion menu, and jquery roundabout for a list of images. However it seems the jquery-ui is conflicting with the roundabout animation:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31272696/ex2.html

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31272696/ex2.html

any solution?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has some build-in effects for animation, which is mixed up with the roundabout code. I got this solved by downloading a custom built jQuery UI without the effects.

The problem should still be narrowed down to exactly what is conflicting and if it could be resolved without leaving out the UI effects. Still I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Not the greatest solution when you need those effects, but I have included some easing library instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by add jquery easing after jquery-ui:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-roundabout/jquery.roundabout.revision.js"></script>
```